# PHP - Not to execute specific code on specific page

Tags: php, if-statement, url

I have one common page: ***default.php***

```
<?php 

  ________Some Codes________

?>
```

And my project has **100+** <kbd>*.php*</kbd> files. (Yes all files have `require_once 'default.php';` on the first line of all pages)

Now, I am deciding to display <kbd>**alert**</kbd> in all the files except **2**. (say ***1.php*** & ***2.php***).

Of course, I'll add that <kbd>**alert**</kbd> in my ***default.php***.

So now my ***default.php*** will look like:

```
<?php

________Some Codes_______


echo $comn_alert = "<script>alert('Hi');</script>";

?>
```

## Question:

How can I stop **`$comn_alert`** from executing on ***1.php*** & ***2.php***?

Comment: In this case, alert can go into a separate file and be included conditionally. Anyway, what does `__FILE__` give you when you add this in default.php?

Comment: Or you can do this current URL check in javascript itself.

Comment: @vivek_23 "*In this case, alert can go into a separate file and be included conditionally*" so I need to add to 98 files individually? Also, "*what does `__FILE__` give you*", I didn't get this.

Comment: PHP doc says for `_FILE__`: "If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.", so I'd guess it wouldn't work

Comment: @Jb31 Thanks for notifying. Had never tried it before so.

Comment: @Pal Can you amend the way you include in just 1.php and 2.php? I think I have an answer.

Comment: @vivek_23 Do you mean including default in 1 & 2? If so, yes I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a constant before including the file and then check if that constant is defined in `default.php`.It would be something like below:

**1.php:**

```
<?php

define('AVOID_ALERT_1',1);

require_once('default.php');
```

**2.php:**

```
<?php

define('AVOID_ALERT_2',1);

require_once('default.php');
```

**default.php:**

```
<?php 

// __some__codes

if(!(defined('AVOID_ALERT_1') || defined('AVOID_ALERT_2'))){
   echo $comn_alert = "<script>alert('Hi');</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several approaches:

- You could use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in `default.php` to check if it's included from either `1.php` or `2.php`
- You could restructure your inclusion structure a little bit: Extract the common logic of `default.php` (i.e. the logic used in *all* files) into another file (e.g `default_minimal.php`) and make `default.php` require that file and contain the code in  question (e.g. the `alert()`). Make then `1.php` and `2.php` only require `default_minimal.php`
- Set a variable in `1.php` and `2.php` before requiring and then check in `default.php` for the existence / absence of this variable.

Comment: Yes, I thought of the 3rd way where OP can define a constant before including the file and then check if that constant is defined in default.php.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer (small code) for point 1 & 3. And what are the merits and demerits of them? I'll not go with point 2 as in future if I need to change some codes in default, I'd have to change in the other one too.